# Entity Framework : wrong return type of stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure you can find the logic below, and now when I take this sp to EF {version 5.0} this sp would take return type as int.

```
Create Proc  SP_GetResultBasedOnFilterForCoverage
(
 @AgeID int,
 @IncomeID int,
 @GenderID int,
 @EducationID int,
 @ProductID int
)
as
set nocount on
Declare  @query varchar(max), @index  int, @totalrow int, @coverageTotal bigint
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SecondDataSet') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SecondDataSet
Create table #SecondDataSet
(
CoverageID int,
  Coverage varchar(100),
  Percentage float
) 

Declare @CoverageTable Table
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  CoverageID  int,
  Coverage varchar(100),
  CoverageCount int   
)

insert into @CoverageTable
(CoverageID,Coverage,CoverageCount)
Select TCPC.CoverageID,Coverage.Coverage, COUNT(CustomerID) from TBL_Customer_Product_Choice as  TCPC
inner join 
Tbl_Coverage as coverage
on 
coverage.CoverageID = TCPC.CoverageID
group by 
TCPC.CoverageID,coverage.Coverage



set @index = 1;
Select @totalrow =  COUNT(ID) from @CoverageTable

While(@index <= @totalrow)
begin
Declare @CurrentCoverageID int
Select  @coverageTotal = CoverageCount, @CurrentCoverageID = CoverageID from @CoverageTable where id = @index
set @query  = '
 Insert into #SecondDataSet 
 (Percentage,CoverageID,Coverage)

Select Round((Cast(COUNT(TCPC.CustomerID) as float)/cast('+cast(@coverageTotal as varchar)+' as  bigint)) * 100,1)  as Percentage ,
TCPC.CoverageID ,TC.Coverage 
from  Tbl_customer_Product_Choice as TCPC
inner  join 
Tbl_Coverage as  TC
on 
TCPC.CoverageID = TC.CoverageID
Where productID = cast('+cast(@ProductID as varchar)+'as int)  and TCPC.CoverageID = cast('+ cast(@CurrentCoverageID as varchar)+' as  int)'

if(@AgeID <> 0)
begin

  set  @query += ' and  AgeID = ' + CAST(@AgeID as  varchar);
End

if( @IncomeID != 0)
begin
  set  @query += ' and  IncomeID = ' + CAST(@IncomeID as  varchar);
End

if(@EducationID != 0)
begin
  set  @query += ' and  EducationID = ' + CAST(@EducationID as  varchar);
End

if(@GenderID > -1)
begin
  set  @query += ' and  GenderID = ' + CAST(@GenderID as  varchar);
End

set @query += ' group  by  TCPC.CoverageID,TC.Coverage
order by  COUNT(TCPC.CustomerID) desc
'
Exec(@query)
set  @index = @index + 1;
end

Select * from #SecondDataSet
```

Comment: What version of EF you are using? Is it code-first or db-first or something else? Add more details to your question and generated code you are getting, otherwise it is imposible to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: DB-first  and version 5.0

Comment: How are you importing the stored procedure in entity framework db first?

Comment: return type of int is a default. Did you set explicitly what return type SP has ?

Comment: Importing Store procedure , by  update model from database model option

Comment: vittore :: I have tried to set  Complex type  bt it also doesn't seems to work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593473/ef-cant-infer-return-schema-from-stored-procedure-selecting-from-a-temp-table

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this problem. EF can not auto generate SP. We should add it manually. As a result, I applied the following methods.

Its my example SP:

---

```
CREATE TABLE #LocalTempTable
(
    c1 INT,
    c2 INT, 
    c3 NVARCHAR(50),
    c4 INT
)

SELECT * FROM #LocalTempTable
```

---

Add a new complex type (for temp table returns column):

1-Open `.edmx` file from Solution Explorer

2-Right click to empty space from opened windows then "Add New -> Complex Type"

3-Rename type and Right click renamed type on Model Browser then "Add -> Scalar Property -> COLUMN_TYPE"

My SP return 4 column. `int32` , `int32`, `string`, `int32`. If return type is `nullable` you can change from properties window

5- Now we can import SP from Database. Right click Function Imports on Model Browser then "Add Function Import"

6- Write a custom name (NOTE: use this name codebehind) Chosee Stored Procedure. Tick Complex, select created complex type then ok.

Now test SP

```
DBEntities db = new SIRAMATIKEntities();
List<complex_type> result= db.FunctionName(data).ToList();
```

If returned column names different complex type columb, you can change from Mapping Details. In Model Browser Right click created function then click "Function Import Mapping".

I hope it helped. I'm sorry if spelling mistakes. I use translate.