# Generate stored procedures for Entity Framework with Reverse POCO generator

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using Entity Framework Reverse POCO Generator 2.19.0 to work with an existing database

Everything is fine until I add a sproc that does a SELECT from multiple tables (including temporal ones) and I expect the tool (POCO Generator) to generate an Entity to store the returned values from that sproc but it justs generates a function that returns an Int instead of the expected object.

**How should I structure the sproc or what kind of SELECT the poco generator expects?**

Here's the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAccountStatement] --Historial de transacciones
@MembershipID BIGINT
, @pagina INT = 1
, @npag INT = 100
AS
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @offset INT,
        @NumeroTransacciones BIGINT,
        @AccountID BIGINT

SELECT
    @offset = (@pagina - 1) * @npag

SET FMTONLY OFF

SELECT
    transactionCheck_Rel.CheckID,
    AmountTotal AS Accrual,
    0 AS Redemption INTO #TransactionAux_t4
FROM transactionCheck_Rel
JOIN [transaction]
    ON [transaction].TransactionID = transactionCheck_Rel.TransactionID
    AND TransactionTypeID = 4

SELECT
    transactionCheck_Rel.CheckID,
    0 AS Accrual,
    AmountTotal AS Redemption INTO #TransactionAux_t3
FROM transactionCheck_Rel
JOIN [transaction]
    ON [transaction].TransactionID = transactionCheck_Rel.TransactionID
    AND TransactionTypeID = 3


SELECT
    #TransactionAux_t4.CheckID,
    #TransactionAux_t4.Accrual,
    ISNULL(#TransactionAux_t3.redemption, 0) AS redemption INTO #TransactionAux
FROM #TransactionAux_t4
LEFT JOIN #TransactionAux_t3
    ON #TransactionAux_t3.CheckID = #TransactionAux_t4.CheckID
ORDER BY #TransactionAux_t4.CheckID

INSERT INTO #TransactionAux
    SELECT
        #TransactionAux_t3.CheckID,
        #TransactionAux_t3.Accrual,
        ISNULL(#TransactionAux_t3.redemption, 0) AS redemption
    FROM #TransactionAux_t3

SELECT
    #TransactionAux.CheckID,
    [dbo].[check].StoreID,
    store.SystemName,
    dbo.[check].NetAmount,
    account.AccountID,
    #TransactionAux.Accrual,
    #TransactionAux.redemption,
    account.InitialBalance,
    account.FinalBalance,
    dbo.[transaction].TransactionID,
    dbo.[transaction].BusinessDate,
    dbo.membershipAccount_Rel.MembershipID

FROM dbo.account
LEFT JOIN dbo.assignCheck
    ON assignCheck.AccountID = account.AccountID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[check]
    ON [check].CheckID = assignCheck.CheckID
LEFT JOIN #TransactionAux
    ON #TransactionAux.CheckID = [check].CheckID
JOIN dbo.[transaction]
    ON [transaction].AccountID = account.AccountID
JOIN dbo.transactionDetail
    ON transactionDetail.TransactionID = [transaction].TransactionID
LEFT JOIN transactionCheck_Rel
    ON transactionCheck_Rel.TransactionID = [transaction].TransactionID
LEFT JOIN dbo.store
    ON store.StoreID = [check].StoreID
JOIN dbo.membershipAccount_Rel
    ON membershipAccount_Rel.AccountID = account.AccountID
ORDER BY membershipAccount_Rel.MembershipID ASC OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @npag ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Can you show the sproc? I'm using version 2.18.1 and have no issue with the POCO generator creating the method in the context along with the ReturnModel.

Comment: @BBauer42 I added it to the question

Comment: Are you manually doing anything funky in the .tt file? For example, the StoredProcedureFilterExclude, or sections under stored procedure renaming / return types? Have you tried creating a simple sproc that selects one or two fields to see if that generates a ReturnModel?

Comment: Nothing funky, have not touched the StoredProcedurFilters. I tried a query with multiple joins and everything worked, the returnModel was generated correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is what Simon Hughes, the author of the reverse POCO generator states in the [discussion forum for the project](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/view/Discussions/3) as a response to this question.

**Question**:

> "I have Temp Table using in Stored PRoc. But the class is not
>   generated due to using this temp table in SP"

**Answer**:

> "Nothing that can be done in the generator. What you can do however is
>   to change the stored procedure into a table valued function, and
>   define the table you are returning. I'm sure I recently mentioned this
>   somewhere and gave an example."

I have looked through the discussion forum further and have yet to find the example he references. You may be better off asking your question directly on that forum. I have asked questions there before and Simon is very responsive.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593473/ef-cant-infer-return-schema-from-stored-procedure-selecting-from-a-temp-table) may also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @BBauer42. Just seen this now :-) Better late than never...
There should be a return model generated for the sproc. If not, then yes, try wrapping the stored procedure with a table valued function that correctly declares the column types being returned.

Comment: Alternatively try using a fake data contract to declare the return types http://stackoverflow.com/a/16594665/5884