# Entity Framework 6 returning wrong type for complex stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that explicitly lists a number of columns as it's result. When I add the stored procedure to Entity Framework v6, it doesn't add a `_result.cs` file, and it sees the stored procedure as simply returning an int.

Can anyone see what I am not?

```
@UserIn int,
@Lat float,
@Lng float
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @or geography, @dest  geography
    select @or = geography::Point(@Lat, @Lng, 4326)

    select 
        Uid, SongKickId, SongKickArtistId, DisplayName, Type, Uri, 
        StartDate, StartDateTime, City, Lat, Lng, Capacity, ArtistId, 
        CreateDate, CreateUserId, IsActive, TwitterMsg, SocialMsg,
        Cast(0.0 as float) as [dist]
    from 
        SongKickEvent E 
    where 
        (E.Lat is not null and E.Lng is not null)
        and cast(StartDate as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date)
END
```

Comment: Is this the whole SP? I think EF can't discover the output columns.

Comment: Yes it is.  I have another SP that looks just like this (to me) and EF DOES disocover the columns.  I can't quite seem to figure out how to post that.

Comment: Okay. I asked because the input parameters don't seem to do anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have this issue I specify a faux data contract and there you go. I learnt that from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593473/ef-cant-infer-return-schema-from-stored-procedure-selecting-from-a-temp-table) SO post.